# GEO Chart Legend/Datatable

Tags: google-visualization

I'm wondering if it's possible to display a *kind of data table* in GEO Charts. I have this code:

```
        google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);

        function drawMarkersMap() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();


            data.addColumn('string', 'Country');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
            data.addRow(["AT",141]);
            data.addRow(["BE",8]);
            data.addRow(["CH",42]);
            data.addRow(["DE",98]);
            data.addRow(["ES",942]);
            data.addRow(["GR",30]);
            data.addRow(["HQ",104]);
            data.addRow(["HU",30]);
            data.addRow(["LU",10]);
            data.addRow(["NL",153]);
            data.addRow(["PL",53]);
            data.addRow(["PT",102]);
            data.addRow(["RU",266]);
            data.addRow(["SE",13]);
            data.addRow(["TR",228]);                
            var options = {
                displayMode: 'regions',
                region: '150',
                colorAxis: {colors: ['#ffa3b5', 'red']},
                tooltip: { textStyle: { fontName: '"Verdana"', fontSize: 14 } },
                legend: {textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 10}},
                keepAspectRatio: false,
                height: 300,
                width: 550
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_02'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

As I have some special countries (like **HQ**) and **Turkey** (that is not in region 150), I would like to a *datatable or legend* to the geochart.

Is this possible or do I have to make a table charts and put it somewhere else on the website?

Cheers & Thx in Advance
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a dataTable to the geoChart using the native Google Visualization API. A GeoChart is a GeoChart and a DataTable is a DataTable. However, you can create a linked GeoChart and DataTable on the same page using the same data taking advantage of the [Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#controlwrapperobject) controls and chartwrappers.

If you get fancy with your CSS, you can even hover the `<div>` with the table over the GeoChart, or otherwise find a way to make it *look* like they are the same chart.